# How to extend a warpPerspective image once warped?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to do an "extended" warpPerspective, my idea is to identify 4 points to find a homography matrix and then do a warpPerspective to get the out image in a "correct way" (please observe resistance.jpeg and warp.png)

But what I need is, having identified these 4 points, I would like to have the rest of the box (of course you can ask to me, why I take the internal square and not the 4 points of box?, let say I cannot always have the external 4 points, this is an example I want to implement on a project I'm working on) (please observe the expected)

I'm using python 3.11 and OpenCV 4.7
[resistance.jpeg - original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwEEL.jpg)
[warp.png - warped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRk4j.jpg)
[What I expect - Expectation based on internal 4 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwdQ6.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

src = cv2.imread('resistance.jpeg')

src_pts = [[195,470],[144,1406],[1151,1430],[1130,394]]
src_pts = np.array(src_pts)
dst_pts =  [[0,0], [0,700], [696,700],[696,0]]
dst_pts = np.array(dst_pts)

mat, some = cv2.findHomography(srcPoints=src_pts, dstPoints=dst_pts)
out = cv2.warpPerspective(src, mat, (696, 700))

cv2.imwrite('warp.png',out)
```

I tried manipulating the cv2.warpPerspective tuple, but if set for example (772,1044) (what is the dimension of box in pixels approximately), it expands from right and below, I think this occurs due warped image (warp.png) starts from (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

The third argument you passed is the size of the output image, you made it equal to the size of the rectified inner rectangle, so that's what you got.

What you want to pass is the size of the rectangle obtained after rectifying the four outer vertices of the box with the same homography you have found. Take the original coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right corners of the box. Find their warped coordinates using `cv2.perspectiveTrasform(array_of_outer_points, mat)`, then compute their differences in x and y: these are the width and height that you need to plug into `cv2.warpPerspective`.

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT

This is what I got in a quick'n'dirty colab notebook

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from google.colab import files
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the image from local disk
os.unlink('resistance.jpg')
uploaded=files.upload()
```

resistance.jpg(image/jpeg) - 546359 bytes, last modified: n/a - 100% done

Saving resistance.jpg to resistance.jpg

```
# Convert it to numpy array
in_img = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(uploaded['resistance.jpg'])))

# Using Gimp, identify the outer corners of the box, and the
# "rounded" corners of the inner square 
outer_corners = np.float32(np.array(((144,261), (1194,138), (1249,1767), (51,1680))))
inner_corners = np.float32(np.array(((207,486),(1110,414),(1137,1398),(162,1383))))

# Map the inner corners to an axis-aligned square, offset 
# enough from the image left and top side so that the outer
# corners will fit in the image after warping. I arbitrarily
# choose the size to be 800x800, but if unit scaling were
# needed I would compute the area of the inner_corners
# quadrilateral, and make up a square of the same area.
out_inner_corners = np.float32(np.array(((400,400),(1200,400),(1200,1200),(400,1200))))

# Estimate the homography mapping inner_corners to out_inner_corners
H=cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(inner_corners, out_inner_corners)
print(H)
```

[[ 1.09417517e+00  9.16917791e-02  1.58073232e+02]

[ 1.31087874e-01  1.07378738e+00 -1.19866159e+02]

[ 1.21497242e-04  9.80952996e-05  1.00000000e+00]]

```
# See where the outer corners would be mapped into. 
out_outer_corners = cv2.perspectiveTransform(outer_corners.reshape((-1,4,2)), H)
print(out_outer_corners)
```

[[[ 325.53592  171.86201]

[1274.9574   159.53275]

[1272.9131  1464.9971 ]

[ 314.19254 1443.8832 ]]]

```
# All looks good, the outer corners are all inside an image of the same shape
# as the input one, so we can warp easily:
out_img = cv2.warpPerspective(in_img, H, dsize=(2048,1536))

# Display it
plt.imshow(out)
```

[image: warp uncropped]

```
# Since we know where the outer corners are mapped, we can easily crop
corners = out_outer_corners.reshape((4,2))
out_top = int(np.round(np.min(corners[:, 1])))
out_bottom = int(np.round(np.max(corners[:, 1])))
out_left = int(np.round(np.min(corners[:, 0])))
out_right = int(np.round(np.max(corners[:, 0])))

out_img_cropped = out_img[out_top:out_bottom, out_left:out_right]
plt.imshow(out_img_cropped)
```

[image: warp cropped]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried with cv2.perspectiveTransform(), but I think I did not understand well how this works, I tried with cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(), but I think I get the same result, what I have located is the inner 4 points rectangle (696x700), but after doing a warp perspective, the top left corner seems to be the coordinate (0,0), I need to find the entire box but i only get the bot and right side from top left corner, I tried with negative coordinates too, but it seems doesnt work as I expected.